# Cannot access sub-keys in OrderedDict

Tags: python, ordereddictionary

I'm trying to define my ordinary dictionary as an OrderedDict, but I can't seem to access keys are the inner level.

```
my_dict = \
{
    'key1':
    {
        'subkey1':value1,
        'subkey2':value2
    }
}

my_ordered_dict = OrderedDict\
([(
    'key1',
    (
        ('subkey1',value1),
        ('subkey2',value2)
    )
)])
```

I can access `['key1']` for both cases, but I cannot access `['key1']['subkey1']` for the ordered dict.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The value in the `OrderedDict` isn't a dictionary, it's a tuple of tuples. If you want it to be another `OrderedDict`, you'll have to do so explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary with 'subkey1' should also be defined as a OrderedDict ,if thats what you want.
So it should be something like this

```
import collections
my_ordered_dict = collections.OrderedDict()
sub_dict=collections.OrderedDict()
sub_dict['subkey1']=1
sub_dict['subkey2']=2
my_ordered_dict['key1']=sub_dict
sub_dict=collections.OrderedDict()
sub_dict['subkey1']=3
sub_dict['subkey2']=4
my_ordered_dict['key2']=sub_dict
print my_ordered_dict['key1']['subkey1']
print my_ordered_dict['key2']['subkey1']
```

The out put will be

```
1
3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the inner level to also be an `OrderedDict` you need to explicitly define it as one. Since argument order matters when constructing `OrderedDict`s, in order to preserve it, you need to pass the keys and values as a sequence of `key, value` pairs as shown in the [*`OrderedDict` Examples and Recipes*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes) section of the documentation.

Applying that to your example means you would need to do something like the following:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

value1, value2 = 42, 69

my_ordered_dict = OrderedDict([
                    ('key1', OrderedDict([
                                ('subkey1', value1),
                                ('subkey2', value2)
                             ])
                    )
                  ])

print(my_ordered_dict['key1']['subkey1'])  # --> 42
```